# Please how do you make a recursive function out of this question

Tags: python, function, recursion

Question 3
Fill in the blanks to make the is_power_of function return whether the number is a power of the given base. Note: base is assumed to be a positive number. Tip: for functions that return a boolean value, you can return the result of a comparison.

Solution:

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
    for i in range(1, 4):
        if number % base == 0 and base**i == number:
            return True
    return False
print(is_power_of(8, 2)) #Should be True
print(is_power_of(64, 4)) #Should be True


enter code here
```

Comment: What have you tried to make it recursive so far?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is where you call the function within the function. You can change the code to look like this to add recursion to it:

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
    num = number/base

    if (num == base):
        return True
    if (num > base):
        return is_power_of(num,base)

    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert into recursive function.. firstly you need to know the base condition of the recursive function.

we will be doing `number//base` recursively. if the number becomes 1 in this process that means `base^power` can produce that number. if number becomes 0 or if number cannot be divisible by the base means it can not produce number

**base condition for this function**->

(1) `if number == 1: return True`

(2) `if number % base != 0 or number == 0: return False`

Now we know base condition.. we can do the coding part.

**Code:**

```
def is_power_of(number,base):
    if number==1: #Base condition
        return True
    elif number%base != 0 or number==0: #Base condition 
        return False
    else:
        return is_power_of(number//base,base) #Recursively calling 

print(is_power_of(8, 2)) #True
print(is_power_of(64, 4)) #True
```